# Enable ZTS Support on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, apache2, php

i've installed everything that regards PHP from the standard repository. I've installed php5-dev package and all other dependencies to run pthreads on my server.
I don't understand how to enable the ZTS on it...what should i do?
Do i have to download PHP5 from another source? Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I didn't need it anymore